Can't dual-boot to ubuntu from external HDD
I have ubuntu installed on my external HDD to dual boot along my Windows drive. Before you ask all the bios settings are set correctly Fast boot and Secure boot are off and the boot sequence is properly set. Also the EFI partition has the proper flags and despite everything every time I try to boot it just keeps boot looping with the prompt "reset system" in the top left corner instead of grub.
I also tried super grub disk and boot repair.
here are the specs:
enter image description here

Currently running Kubuntu 24.04 from my external SSD drive. Do you have ESP on external drive? Do you have name/label of flash drive as first in UEFI boot order settings? Not one time boot menu. Post link to summary report from Boot-Repair in your question above. External drive is using USB3 port. Often better to use lighter weight flavor for external drives. But Kubuntu is more mid-weight & has worked for me with external SSDs.

Hey thanks. I had the exact same problem with Kubuntu and even Dabian at this point I know the problem is at my end, the OS is properly installed but my pc does recognize it I been trying everything I can for the past week and nothing works, I even tried unplugging the SATA cables of the windows disk
